# PL/SQL - No Data Found error

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, indexing

I'm getting this error "ORA-01403: no data found" when I try to run the following block.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  TYPE dept_table_type IS TABLE OF departments.department_name%TYPE
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  my_dept_table dept_table_type;
  f_loop_count NUMBER(2) :=10;
  v_deptno NUMBER(5) :=0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..f_loop_count LOOP
      v_deptno := v_deptno + 10;
    SELECT department_name
    INTO my_dept_table(i)
    FROM departments
    WHERE department_id = v_deptno;
  END LOOP;
  FOR i IN 1..f_loop_count LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_dept_table(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I'm not 100% sure on the issue. The only thing I can think of is in the DECLARE block it's not doing the INDEX part right - though I'm not sure on how to get it to work.

Cheers

Comment: Well, it means your select statement in not returning anything for one of your v_deptno values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle, when sees **No data** for the Selected query, and you attempt to put it into a variable, will end up throwing an Exception. Because, the `INTO` variable now is left untouched, and the developer had to handle it accordingly !

```
DECLARE
  TYPE dept_table_type IS TABLE OF departments.department_name%TYPE
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  my_dept_table dept_table_type;
  f_loop_count NUMBER(2) :=10;
  v_deptno NUMBER(5) :=0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..f_loop_count LOOP
      v_deptno := v_deptno + 10;
      BEGIN
        SELECT department_name
        INTO my_dept_table(i)
        FROM departments
        WHERE department_id = v_deptno;
      EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data for ' || v_deptno);
         my_dept_table(i) := NULL;
         --Flow continues
      END;
  END LOOP;
  FOR i IN 1..f_loop_count LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_dept_table(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I see, this is out of the Oracle Database PLSQL Fundamentals text book, and it didn't account for some of the department ids not existing, or at least that they've been modified. It didn't even occur to me to put an Exception in. Thanks very much :)